# jQuery Mobile and MVVM challenges

Tags: jquery-mobile, mvvm, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am having some challenges trying to use JQM and MVVM. I am also trying to use knockout.js too.

For example, currently I am trying to implement a navigation similar to the iOS page control(the little dots indicating you can swipe to navigate to the next page):

[image: Page indicator]

The data to be displayed is fetched from the server and it needs to be displayed in JQM pages. So the JQM pages need to be created dynamically.

From the UI perspective, I plan to use a fixed footer containing the dots(based on the number of pages).

The problem is with the view-model which needs to persist between the JQM pages, as I do not want to load data from the server by page, data is loaded at once and it is expected that the client will display it in pages.

I could have a view-model holding the data and living through-out the life of the application and just bind each page view to it.
Instead, I want to keep the view-model alive as long as it's really required by the view.

The solution I am thinking is to catch jQueryMobile page navigation events and see if the navigation is between these pages.
If it's not, the view-model should be removed(assigning it to null).
Next time if any of these pages needs to be loaded(for example by navigating back to the last page), the view model is re-created(data is fetched from web-site again).

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the [Persistent Footers page](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/footer-persist-a.html) on the jQueryMobile documentation.

Comment: I already clearly mentioned that I am going to use those. That's not the idea of my question. The problem is how to keep the view model alive.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try the [JQM pagination plugin](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_mobile_pagination_plugin/) along with the persistent footer @calavoow mentions?

That would give you dragable JQM pages with a set footer.

Comment: Im sorry but you also did not seem to understand my question.

Comment: So, you want multiple pages "in one view", so you don't have to refetch any pages that are not visible as the user swipes through? You could try JQMs multipage, which will allow you to load "x-pages-in-one-document". If you have page A,B,C,D in your "view" you can then setup something to navigate between them without having to refetch anything from the server. Your view stays alive

Comment: Multipage is tricky though, because you cannot load a multipage from an already existing page. JQM multipage basically requires your whole app to be within the multipage/view (unless you rel="external"-link to other JQM pages (no transitions!). You could also have a look at my [multiview plugin](https://github.com/frequent/multiview). It's still work-in-progress but you could have single panel inside a JQM wrapper page and put all your swipe-pages inside this panel.

Comment: You can also [prefetch pages](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-cache.html) so that they are already loaded in the DOM.

Comment: thanks, I already know that. The question was how to design the viewmodel to be persistent across specific pages